# ckan 500 error, cant find solr, ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, tomcat, solr

I installed tomcat/solr following the instructions found here and ckan following these instructions on my ubuntu 14.04.
since the installation instructions of ckan is based on jetty, i skipped the part that says

> Edit the Jetty configuration file (/etc/default/jetty) and change the following variables:
>
> ```
> NO_START=0            # (line 4)
> JETTY_HOST=127.0.0.1  # (line 15)
> JETTY_PORT=8983       # (line 18)
> ```

I think that might be the problem cos i cant find where to set up solr. When i try to run ckan `paster serve /etc/ckan/default/development.ini` i get these errors/warnings

> 2015-06-07 09:27:29,048 ERROR [ckan.lib.search.common] [Errno 111]
>   Connection refused Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/search/common.py", line 51,
>   in is_available
>     conn.query("*:*", rows=1)
>
> File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py",
>   line 703, in query return 
>     self.select(*args, **params)
>
> File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py",
>   line 798, in **call**
>     xml = self.raw(**params)
>
> File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py",
>   line 823, in raw
>     rsp = conn._post(self.selector, request, conn.form_headers)
>
> File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py",
>   line 646, in _post
>     self._reconnect()
>
> File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py",
>   line 625, in _reconnect
>      self.conn.connect()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 772, in connect
>       self.timeout, self.source_address)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
>       raise err 
>   error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
>
> 2015-06-07 09:27:29,111 WARNI [ckan.lib.search] Problems were found while
>   connecting to the SOLR server
>
> 2015-06-07 09:27:30,449 ERROR [ckan.lib.search.common] [Errno 111] Connection refused Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/search/common.py", line 51,
>   in is_available
>       conn.query("*:*", rows=1)
>
> File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py",
>   line 703, in query
>       return self.select(*args, **params)
>
> File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py",
>   line 798, in **call**
>       xml = self.raw(**params)
>
> File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py",
>   line 823, in raw
>       rsp = conn._post(self.selector, request, conn.form_headers)
>
> File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py",
>   line 646, in _post
>       self._reconnect()
>
> File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py",
>   line 625, in _reconnect
>       self.conn.connect()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 772, in connect
>       self.timeout, self.source_address)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
>       raise err
>
> error: [Errno 111] Connection refused 
>   2015-06-07 09:27:30,454
>
> WARNI [ckan.lib.search] Problems were found while connecting to the SOLR server
>
> 2015-06-07 09:27:30,792 CRITI [ckan.lib.uploader] Please specify a ckan.storage_path in your config for your uploads
>
> Starting server in PID 4186. serving on 0.0.0.0:5000 view at http://127.0.0.1:5000

i found the solr xml file, but i couldnt see what i should change.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that for some reason ckan installation by default, on the config file (default located at `/etc/ckan/development.ini` or `/etc/ckan/production.ini`) has this line `solr_url=http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr` commented. In my case i had to change the port 8983 to 8080, since this is for jetty and not tomcat, that i use.